# Windows audio stutter/lag fullscreen Flash/Html5 Fix

Tags: windows, audio, lag

It took me 3 weeks to find this problem, and i cant find a topic to reply on so i will post it like this.

i forgot about it the last time i did this. After 3 weeks of sound lagging flash movies and html5 movies while working. I decided to clean my processor cooler and video fan and cooler. The slightist amound of dust can cause these lags. While you do this it is recommended you ad some processor fluid. And there you go, the problem is fixed, also make sure you have the latest drivers, video and audio.

Ive seen allot of topics on this matter on other forums, so i know there allot of ppl trying to fix this.
I hope you all can enjoy your pc again soon.

Answer (score 0):

Many codecs are not hardware accelerated.  This is especially true with video on the web.  Because of this, the CPU is overly taxed as it is responsible for decoding the video.  Since the OS has to juggle many threads and handle other software on your machine, anything can distract the CPU from processing your video fast enough to be glitch-free.  This is the reality of video on the web today.

Comment: The last time i had this, i did the same thing, it was on windows 7, and i only had a little anoying game lag, now in windows 8.1 with even less dust i had game lag and sound lag, i am so happy everything is stable again.

Answer (score 0):

**There is one more thing you need to know if you are on windows 8.1.**

If you look at services in system management and you find this service Device Setup Manager(DsmSvc)
By default it is set to manual, but this useless service will over ride your audio drivers, with out you knowing about it.
It is best to turn it off so disable it, If your having trouble installing your drivers. 
This is a real anoying service, you wont notice it doing that until you install your audio drivers for like 30 times or so.
If you turn it off and install your audio drivers, re enable it again. then you will see it...
Secret window pops up minimized, and it happens real fast.